# Prevent duplicate COUNT in SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have the following query which as you can see does multiple `Count(CompetitorID)` calls. Is this a performance issue, or does SQL Server 2008 'cache' the `Count`? If this is a performance issue, is it possible to store the `Count` to prevent the multiple lookups?

```
SELECT EventID,Count(CompetitorID) AS NumberRunners,
    CASE WHEN Count(CompetitorID)<5 THEN 1
         WHEN Count(CompetitorID)>=5 AND Count(CompetitorID)<=7 THEN 2
         ELSE 3 END AS NumberPlacings
FROM Comps
GROUP BY EventID Order By EventID;
```

Comment: Although the syntax makes it appear that you are repeating an operation, the query analyzer is likely to optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its always a better practice to get the value once and use it subsequently whenever possible. In your case, you can always use Inner query to get the count only once and compute other (derived) columns off its value as shown below:

```
SELECT  EventID, NumberRunners,
        CASE WHEN NumberRunners <5 THEN 1
             WHEN NumberRunners >=5 AND NumberRunners <=7 THEN 2
             ELSE 3 
        END AS NumberPlacings
  FROM  (
            SELECT  EventID,
                    NumberRunners = Count(CompetitorID)
              FROM  Comps
            GROUP BY EventID
        ) t
Order By EventID;
```

Comment: Thanks Akhil, I assumed it wasn't good to be counting multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

simplest would be this:

SELECT EventID,Count(distinct CompetitorID) AS NumberRunners,
    CASE WHEN Count(distinct CompetitorID)<5 THEN 1
         WHEN Count(distinct CompetitorID)>=5 AND Count(distinct CompetitorID)<=7 THEN 2
         ELSE 3 END AS NumberPlacings
FROM Comps
GROUP BY EventID Order By EventID;